# How to return result to a fragment from recycler view

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview

I have an activity B with fragment B which I open from activity A using `startActivityForResult`. Inside my fragment B, I have a recycler grid view. In grid view I have grid of web-views for displaying animated gifs.

My fragment B code

```
public static class GiphyFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private GiphyTestAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public GiphyFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_giphy_test, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.giphy_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a grid layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter
    ArrayList<Giphy> giphyDataSet = new ArrayList<Giphy>();
    mAdapter = new GiphyTestAdapter(getActivity(),giphyDataSet);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //run async task to fetch list of giphys
    ...
    ...

    return rootView;
}
}
```

GiphyTestAdapter

```
public class GiphyTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GiphyTestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<Giphy> mDataset;
private Context mContext;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public WebView giphyView;
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        giphyView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.giphy_view);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.giphy_url);
        this.giphyView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, textView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                //Here I want to return result to fragment so that it can give it to activity A
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void add(int position, Giphy giphyObj) {
    mDataset.add(giphyObj);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public GiphyTestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Giphy> myDataset) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public GiphyTestAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_giphy_item_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Giphy giphy = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.giphyView.loadUrl(giphy.getUrl());
    holder.textView.setText(giphy.getUrl());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}
}
```

**goal** I want to return result to activity A.

Normally I would do that in fragment B by creating an intent, adding the required result using put extra and calling finish.

In the code above I have data to be returned in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. How to give it fragment B so that it can create intent and return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `getActivity().setResult(int responseCode, Intent data)` and in Activity A, override the `Activity.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Fragment B needs to have an interface that Activity B implements.  Once you have the data in the Fragment just call the interface passing the data to the Activity which can then set the intent and call finish so Activity A will get the result.

No different than an onFragmentInteraction() interface :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of @Degreat Yartey works.

But there are other two ways worth trying:

1.register a BoadcastReceiver is FragmentA and send a broadcast in ActivityB;

2.use an interface to do it.

Comment: this may not be good, if FragmentA recieves receiver before it becomes visible to user,  it can give Null pointer exception when you try to access views from receiver.

Comment: you are right!Maybe sometimes the data can be saved in a Service or Application.